# on convergence of bilateral series in complex analysis

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

the exercise is the following show that for $0\le r$$<1$ the series $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} r^{|n|} e^{i n \theta}$ converge as $\theta$ is real .

I don't know if this is wrong or not but the first thing that came to me is that this expression is a power series because of powers of n  . So I have divides the series in 2 parts and found for both radious \begin{aligned}
& S_1(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(r e^{i \theta}\right)^m \\
& S_2(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{r}{e^{i \theta}}\right)^n \\
& \Rightarrow \quad-e^{-i \theta}<r_2<e^{-i \theta} \\
& -e^{i \theta}<r_2<e^{i \theta} \\
& \Rightarrow-e^{-i \theta}<r<e^{-i \theta} \quad \theta \in \mathbb{R}
\end{aligned}

Shouldn't r be real or is it ok ?

express the series in simple terms

the books here writes
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} r^{|n|} e^{i n \theta}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^0 r^{|n|} e^{i n \theta}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} r^n e^{i n \theta}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^n e^{-i n \theta}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} r^n e^{i n \theta}
$$
so that
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} r^{|n|} e^{i n \theta}=\frac{1}{1-r e^{-i \theta}}+\frac{r e^{i \theta}}{1-r e^{i \theta}}
$$

I know in genral that if a series from **0 to $\infty$** is absolutely convergent you can divide the series  also for this "bilateral series " is still true ?

Comment: $r$ is real, it's $e^{i\theta}$ that isn't.  But note that when $\theta$ is real, $\left| e^{i\theta}\right| = 1$.  The condition for a complex geometric series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$  is $|z| < 1$.  That is **not** the same as $-1 < z < 1$ when $z$ is complex.